# DOMXpath: How to group h3 that have a table tag right afterwards

Tags: php, parsing, xml-parsing, domxpath

I have to parse a page and output `<h3>` and the `<table>` components (seperatly) that comes right afterwards.

there are cases where there are `<p>` tags after the h3 tag like: `<h3> title </h3> <p> some text </p>` which are fine if i output the content of the p tag.

how do i parse an html page and group `<h3>`s with the element right after them?

(full code described here - [PHP DOMDocument: How to make sure I get 2 elements that are h3+table one after an other and not h3+p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47128248/php-domdocument-how-to-make-sure-i-get-2-elements-that-are-h3table-one-after-a))

Comment: Do these elements have a common parent element?

Comment: in that case this wasnt a problem. no, only the body tag wraps them.